# boost::asio is riddled with warnings

Tags: c++, boost, warnings, boost-asio

This program doesn't actually do anything, but it builds with [182 warnings](http://pastebin.com/DKCXWdjc), all of which seem to be issues in `boost` code. Should I do anything about this, maybe use a different library, or should I just use `boost::asio` and ignore all the warnings?

---

```
// main.cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

int main() {
    exit(0) ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is common for many boost (and third-party) libraries. I would have them treated as [system headers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html). For example, with gcc pass the `-isystem` command line option or move the boost headers to directory which is considered a system header directory.

Boost also has a [warnings guidelines page](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/Guidelines/WarningsGuidelines) which might be helpful. See `Suppressing Warnings in GCC`.